# 2 user accounts in my name on fresh installation win10 - how to disable or restrict the second one

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have installed windows 10 pro with first account which has some login and is under my name. But after some time I saw there is one more account under my name which I cannot edit in lusrmgr because it is invisible there.  I can see this account for example at security tab of some start folders. How can I manage to have just one account there? Or if not possible, how to add zero rights to the second one?

I have no use case for the second one.

For example I have two accounts on my computer. Lets suppose my name is John Travolta.  My initial account which I created is `ABCDE/jtrav`.  On some folders, especially at start menu, I see there are two accounts with some rights on it.

First one is ABCDE/jtrav and second one is "John Travolta" and it has different rights to that folder.

Comment: **It's to late to close or delete the question.**  You already asked the question.\and I just spent 10 minutes writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have installed windows 10 pro with first account which has some login and is under my name. But after some time I saw there is one more account under my name which I cannot edit in lusrmgr because it is invisible there. I can see this account for example at security tab of some start folders.

**What you describe is perfectly normally.**  When you created your account a local account that exists on your machine was created.  The account `jtrav` was created on a machine called `ABCDE.  A new account was also created when you linked` jtrav` to your Microsoft Account.

> How can I manage to have just one account there? Or if not possible, how to add zero rights to the second one?

You could remove `jtrav` from the ACL if you wanted, but I don't suggest you do that, it has permissions in the event you unlink your Microsoft Account.  **You should proceed with caution if you go against this recommendation.**

> For example I have two accounts on my computer. Lets suppose my name is John Travolta. My initial account which I created is ABCDE/jtrav. On some folders, especially at start menu, I see there are two accounts with some rights on it.
>
> First one is ABCDE/jtrav and second one is "John Travolta" and it has different rights to that folder.

`ABCDE/jtrav` indicates the account only exists on that specific machine while John Travolta is an indication the account is linked to a Microsoft Account. **They are the same exact account.** Once you link a local account to a Microsoft Account, only the Microsoft Account can be managed, `ABCDE/jtrav` still technically exists but it cannot be used to access your system.

**It's unnecessary to modify the permissions of `ABCDE/jtrav` especially on a folder like the Start Menu.**