# How to remove a phantom/default (?) user in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

A while ago I had to hard-wipe my Windows install drive and reinstall Windows from scratch. I was able to log in to my Microsoft account with my copy of Windows linked, howerver it made the user directory `C:/Users/jacks`. This wasn't exactly an issue but now after a recent update, everytime I turn my PC on [I get a 'Username or password is incorrect...'. message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDgqt.png). From there, [I'm able go back and log in to my account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsEKf.jpg) just fine.

There's only one account listed when I look in the Settings > Accounts menu and in the Control Panel: my blue profile picture one, but the `jacks` user  when I do `wmic useraccount list full` in the Command Prompt, so I assume there's just a missing link somewhere.

Is there anyway to remove this phantom Jacq, or rename/link up the two accounts?

Comment: If you are sure you want to delete that account you can try to delete it via command-line `net user username /DELETE`. But to make sure I strongly recommend to make a full backup before doing so (performing a full backup on a weekly/monthly base is always a good idea).

Comment: Ideally I'd like not to delete the user (everything's under `C:/Users/jacks`, should have made that clear, my bad). I know there's guide out there on how to rename the directory properly but it would stop the logging in issue :/

Comment: Sounds more you are simply want to hide the user account on login screen: https://superuser.com/a/236762/62676

Comment: [Do Not Delete the user in question.  It’s your actual user account.](https://superuser.com/questions/1628176/2-user-accounts-in-my-name-on-fresh-installation-win10-how-to-disable-or-restr/1628190#1628190)

Comment: @Robert I tried to hide the user, but it hid the wrong one? I think it's showing both a local account and a microsoft account. When I removed my microsoft account it seemed to function "normally" (though i prefer if I didn't have to login every time, another problem to solve later).